# Average amount needed for x number of months remaining

Tags: average

I'm trying to calculate the average amount of profit needed to hit a milestone based on the number of months remaining.

So let's say the goal is £1,000 and there are 5 months left. If I have £400 currently how can I calculate how much needs to be made in the remaining 5 months? I've tried a few calculations but I seem to be way off so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You check how much more do you need, thats $1000-400 = 600$ and then divide that by the number of months, in this case it's 5. So you'll need to earn at average $120$ dollars per month in the next 5 months in order to reach the goal.

Comment: It seems so simple now, thanks

Comment: You're welcome. Hope it helps.